# List of the contacts in database

Tags: android, listview

In my app I need to show the list of contact in listView, this list has stored in database.

I have this :

Contact.class :

```
public class Contact {

    private int CTC_ID;
    private byte[]  CTC_IMAGE;
    public String CTC_NOM;
    public String CTC_NUMERO;

    public Contact(){
    }

    public Contact(byte[] CTC_IMAGE, String CTC_NOM, String CTC_NUMERO){
        this.CTC_IMAGE = CTC_IMAGE;
        this.CTC_NOM = CTC_NOM;
        this.CTC_NUMERO = CTC_NUMERO;
    }
    public Contact(String CTC_NOM, String CTC_NUMERO){
        this.CTC_NOM = CTC_NOM;
        this.CTC_NUMERO = CTC_NUMERO;
    }



    public int getCTC_ID(){
        return CTC_ID;
    }
    public byte[] getCTC_IMAGE(){return CTC_IMAGE; }
    public String getCTC_NOM() {
        return CTC_NOM;
    }
    public String getCTC_NUMERO() {
        return CTC_NUMERO;
    }

    public void setCTC_ID(int CTC_ID) {
        this.CTC_ID = CTC_ID;
    }
    public void setCTC_IMAGE(byte[] CTC_IMAGE) { this.CTC_IMAGE = CTC_IMAGE;}
    public void setCTC_NOM(String CTC_NOM) { this.CTC_NOM = CTC_NOM;}
    public void setCTC_NUMERO(String CTC_NUMERO) {
        this.CTC_NUMERO = CTC_NUMERO;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "ID : "+CTC_ID+"\nimage : "+CTC_IMAGE+"\nnom : "+CTC_NOM+"\nnumero : "+CTC_NUMERO;
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Logcat tag
    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "kids_phone";

    // Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACT = "Contact";
    private static final String TABLE_MESSAGE = "Message";
    private static final String TABLE_ASSOCIER = "Associer";

    // Common column names
    private static final String KEY_CTC_ID = "CTC_ID";
    private static final String KEY_MES_ID = "MES_ID";
    private static final String KEY_ASS_ID = "ASS_ID";

    // Contact Table - column names
    public static final String KEY_CTC_IMAGE = "CTC_IMAGE";
    public static final String KEY_CTC_NOM = "CTC_NOM";
    public static final String KEY_CTC_NUMERO = "CTC_NUMERO";

    // Message Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_MES_TITRE = "MES_TITRE";
    private static final String KEY_MES_CONTENU = "MES_CONTENU";

    // Associer Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_ASS_IMG = "ASS_IMG";
    private static final String KEY_ASS_MES_ID = "ASS_MES_ID";
    private static final String KEY_ASS_CTC_ID = "ASS_CTC_ID";

    // Contact table Create Statements
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_CONTACT + " (" + KEY_CTC_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_CTC_IMAGE
            + " BLOB," + KEY_CTC_NOM + " TEXT," + KEY_CTC_NUMERO + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    // Message table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MESSAGE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MESSAGE
            + " (" + KEY_MES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_MES_TITRE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MES_CONTENU + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    // Associer table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ASSOCIER = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_ASSOCIER + " (" + KEY_ASS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_ASS_IMG + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ASS_MES_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_ASS_CTC_ID + " INTEGER);";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // creating required tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MESSAGE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ASSOCIER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MESSAGE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ASSOCIER);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private static SQLiteDatabase bdd;
    static ArrayList<Contact> contactListe = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    public void open() {
        //on ouvre la BDD en écriture
        SQLiteDatabase bdd = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        //on ferme l'accès à la BDD
        bdd.close();
    }


    public long insertContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //Création d'un ContentValues (fonctionne comme une HashMap)
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //on lui ajoute une valeur associé à une clé (qui est le nom de la colonne dans laquelle on veut mettre la valeur)
        values.put(KEY_CTC_IMAGE, contact.getCTC_IMAGE());
        values.put(KEY_CTC_NOM, contact.getCTC_NOM());
        values.put(KEY_CTC_NUMERO, contact.getCTC_NUMERO());
        //on insère l'objet dans la BDD via le ContentValues
        long CTC_ID = db.insert(TABLE_CONTACT, null, values);

        return CTC_ID;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllContact() throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACT, new String[]{"CTC_ID _id", KEY_CTC_NOM, KEY_CTC_NUMERO}, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public ArrayList<Contact> fetchAllContactDetail() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACT, new String[]{"CTC_ID _id", KEY_CTC_IMAGE, KEY_CTC_IMAGE, KEY_CTC_NOM, KEY_CTC_NUMERO}, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                byte[] image = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CTC_IMAGE));
                String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CTC_NOM));
                String numero = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CTC_NUMERO));
                contactListe.add(new Contact(image, name, numero));
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return contactListe;
    }
}
```

The ContactAdapter :

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();


    // Constructor
    public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contactList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contactList.addAll(contactList);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return contactList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView img;
        TextView name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, null);

            holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(contact.getCTC_NUMERO());

        byte[] contactImage = contact.getCTC_IMAGE();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(contactImage, 0, contactImage.length);
        holder.img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return row;
    }
}
```

And my mainactivity :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lstViewContact;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                lstViewContact = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContact);

                displayContact();

}

    public void displayContact() {

        //On ouvre la base de données pour écrire dedans
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        final ContactAdapter contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, dbHelper.fetchAllContactDetail());
        lstViewContact.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
    }
}
```

I have 2 contacts in my Database, but when I launch the app he don't show him.

EDIT :

Test add contact :

```
public class AjoutContact extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText recupNom;
    EditText recupNumero;
    Button ajouter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ajout_contact);

        ajouter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AjoutContact);


        recupNom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Nom);
        recupNumero = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Numero);
        ajouter.setOnClickListener(AjoutContact.this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // get image from drawable

        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),

                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        // convert bitmap to byte

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

        byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();

        String chaine = recupNom.getText().toString();
        String chaine2 = recupNumero.getText().toString();

        //Création d'une instance de ma classe MessageBDD
        DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        //Création d'un contact
        Contact contact = new Contact(imageInByte, chaine, chaine2);

        //On insère le contact que l'on vient de créer
        dbh.insertContact(contact);

        Toast.makeText(AjoutContact.this, "Vous avez ajouter le Contact suivant : " + contact , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: i did not see where you are adding data into you database                               dbHelper.insertContact(...)

Comment: You are not notifying the adapter ,after setting your adapter.

Comment: It's in one test class but the contact it's add via insertContact for the moment in need to show my list in the listview.

Comment: Rv Lalwani I don't understand :s

Comment: can you add your test class code over here

Comment: It's add in my answer but it's no't this class is bug, is the ContactAdapter, when I retrieve the contact by fetchAllContact it's good.

Comment: nobody?? I need you're help...